# OpenCL crash when calling finish()

Tags: macos, opencl, sigabrt

I am writing an OpenCL app on mac using c++, and it crashes in certain cases depending on the work size.
The program crashes due to a SIGABRT.

Is there any way to get more information about the error? 
Why is SIGABRT being raised? Can I catch it?

**EDIT:
I realize that this program is a doozie, however I will try to explain it in case anyone would like to take a stab at it.**

Through debugging I discovered that the cause of the SIGABRT was one of the kernels timing out.

The program is a tile-based 3D renderer. It is an OpenCL implementation of this algorithm: https://github.com/ssloy/tinyrenderer

The screen is divided into 8x8 tiles. One of the kernels (the tiler) computes which polygons overlap each tile, storing the results in a data structure called `tilePolys`. A subsequent kernel (the rasterizer), which runs one work item per tile, iterates over the list of polys occupying the tile and rasterizes them.

The tiler writes to an integer buffer which is a list of lists of polygon indices. Each list is of a fixed size (`polysPerTile` + 1 for the count) where the first element is the count and the subsequent `polysPerTile` elements are indices of polygons in the tile. There is one such list per tile.

For some reason in certain cases the tiler writes a very large poly count (`13172746`) to one of the tile's lists in `tilePolys`. This causes the rasterizer to loop for a long time and time out.

The strange thing is that the index to which the large count is written is never accessed by the tiler.

The code for the tiler kernel is below:

```cpp
// this kernel is executed once per polygon
// it computes which tiles are occupied by the polygon and adds the index of the polygon to the list for that tile
kernel void tiler(
        // number of polygons
        ulong nTris,
        // width of screen
        int width,
        // height of screen
        int height,
        // number of tiles in x direction
        int tilesX,
        // number of tiles in y direction
        int tilesY,
        // number of pixels per tile (tiles are square)
        int tileSize,
        // size of the polygon list for each tile
        int polysPerTile,
        // 4x4 matrix representing the viewport
        global const float4* viewport, 
        // vertex positions
        global const float* vertices,
        // indices of vertices
        global const int* indices,
        // array of array-lists of polygons per tile
        // structure of list is an int representing the number of polygons covering that tile, 
        // followed by [polysPerTile] integers representing the indices of the polygons in that tile
        // there are [tilesX*tilesY] such arraylists
        volatile global int* tilePolys)
{
    size_t faceInd = get_global_id(0);

    // compute vertex position in viewport space
    float3 vs[3];
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        // indices are vertex/uv/normal
        int vertInd = indices[faceInd*9+i*3];

        float4 vertHomo = (float4)(vertices[vertInd*4], vertices[vertInd*4+1], vertices[vertInd*4+2], vertices[vertInd*4+3]);

        vertHomo = vec4_mul_mat4(vertHomo, viewport);
        vs[i] = vertHomo.xyz / vertHomo.w;
    }

    float2 bboxmin = (float2)(INFINITY,INFINITY);
    float2 bboxmax = (float2)(-INFINITY,-INFINITY);

    // size of screen
    float2 clampCoords = (float2)(width-1, height-1);

    // compute bounding box of triangle in screen space
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<2; j++) {
            bboxmin[j] = max(0.f, min(bboxmin[j], vs[i][j]));
            bboxmax[j] = min(clampCoords[j], max(bboxmax[j], vs[i][j]));
        }
    }

    // transform bounding box to tile space
    int2 tilebboxmin = (int2)(bboxmin[0] / tileSize, bboxmin[1] / tileSize);
    int2 tilebboxmax = (int2)(bboxmax[0] / tileSize, bboxmax[1] / tileSize);

    // loop over all tiles in bounding box
    for(int x = tilebboxmin[0]; x <= tilebboxmax[0]; x++) {
        for(int y = tilebboxmin[1]; y <= tilebboxmax[1]; y++) {

            // get index of tile
            int tileInd = y * tilesX + x;
            // get start index of polygon list for this tile
            int counterInd = tileInd * (polysPerTile + 1);
            // get current number of polygons in list
            int numPolys = atomic_inc(&tilePolys[counterInd]);
            // if list is full, skip tile
            if(numPolys >= polysPerTile) {
                // decrement the count because we will not add to the list
                atomic_dec(&tilePolys[counterInd]);
            } else {
                // otherwise add the poly to the list
                // the index is the offset + numPolys + 1 as tilePolys[counterInd] holds the poly count
                int ind = counterInd + numPolys + 1;
                tilePolys[ind] = (int)(faceInd);
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

My theories are that either:

- I have incorrectly implemented the atomic functions for reading and incrementing the count
- I am using an incorrect number format causing garbage to be written into `tilePolys`
- One of my other kernels is inadvertently writing into the `tilePolys` buffer

I do not think it is the last one though because if instead of writing `faceInd` to `tilePolys`, I write a constant value, the large poly count disappears.

```cpp
tilePolys[counterInd+numPolys+1] = (int)(faceInd); // this is the problem line
tilePolys[counterInd+numPolys+1] = (int)(5);       // this fixes the issue
```

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with OpenCL C++ interface, but in C most functions return an error code or set an error Argument. Are you checking these?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your kernel is crashing on the GPU itself. You can't really get any extra diagnostics about that directly, at least not on macOS. You'll need to start narrowing down the problem. Some suggestions:

- As the crash is currently happening in `clFinish()` you don't know what asynchronous command is causing the crash. Try switching all your enqueue calls to blocking mode. This should cause it to crash in the call that's actually going wrong.
- Check return/error codes on **all** OpenCL API calls. Sometimes, ignoring an error from an earlier call can cause problems in a later call which relies on earlier results. For example, if creating a buffer fails, passing the result of that buffer creation as a kernel argument will cause problems when trying to run the kernel.
- The most likely reason for the crash is that your OpenCL kernel is accessing memory out of bounds or is otherwise misusing pointers. Re-check any array index calculations.
- Check if the problem occurs with smaller work batches. Scale up from one workgroup (or work item if not using groups) and see if it only occurs beyond a certain work size. This may give you a clue about buffer sizes and array indices that might be causing the crash.
- Systematically comment out parts of your kernel. If the crash goes away if you comment out a specific piece of code, there's a good chance the problem is in that code.
- If you've narrowed the problem down to a small area of code but can't work out where it's coming from, start recording diagnostic output to check that variables have the values you're expecting.

Without seeing any code, I can't give you any more specific advice than that.

Note that OpenCL is deprecated on macOS, so if you're specifically targeting that platform and don't need to support Linux, Windows, etc. I recommend learning Metal Compute instead. Apple has made it clear that this is the GPU programming platform they want to support, and the tooling for it is already much better than their OpenCL tooling ever was.

I suspect Apple will eventually stop implementing OpenCL support when they release a Mac with a new type of GPU, so even if you're targeting the Mac as well as other platforms, you will probably need to switch to Metal on the Mac somewhere down the line anyway. As of macOS 10.14, the minimum system requirements of the OS already include a Metal-capable GPU, so you only need OpenCL as a fallback if you wish to support all Mac models able to run 10.13 or an even older OS version.

Comment: This is a great answer so I just want to add to it as a comment. I'd comment out all reads and writes in the kernel to see if the crash goes away. Then work backwards. Sometimes I get some luck from debugging the kernels with device side `printf`s.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive response. I have edited the question to include some code in case anyone would like to take a gander.